# Cloud Function with pubsub trigger topic is not working

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-pubsub

I have wrote a simple code to print data and context from a pubsub trigger cloud function.

def main(event, context):
"""Background Cloud Function to be triggered by Pub/Sub.
Args:
event (dict):  The dictionary with data specific to this type of
event. The `data` field contains the PubsubMessage message. The
`attributes` field will contain custom attributes if there are any.
context (google.cloud.functions.Context): The Cloud Functions event
metadata. The `event_id` field contains the Pub/Sub message ID. The
`timestamp` field contains the publish time.
"""
import base64

```
print("""This Function was triggered by messageId {} published at {}
""".format(context.event_id, context.timestamp))

if 'data' in event:
    name = base64.b64decode(event['data']).decode('utf-8')
else:
    name = 'World'
print('Hello {}!'.format(name))
```

Cloud function is deployed successfully but whenever I publish a message to the trigger topic in logs I cannot see any function execution statement.

I have already verified that I am calling main function only and publishing to a right pubsub topic.

I cannot see any error statement so I am not able to debug.

Any Suggestion will be helpful

Answer (score 2):

I tested your code function in `python 3.8` runtime and all works fine, are you using the same pub/sub topic for push new messages?

This the code that I used on my computer to send pubsub messages.

```py
from google.cloud import pubsub_v1

publisher = pubsub_v1.PublisherClient()
# The `topic_path` method creates a fully qualified identifier
# in the form `projects/{project_id}/topics/{topic_id}`
topic_path = publisher.topic_path("myprojectID", "test")

for n in range(1, 10):
    data = u"Message number {}".format(n)
    # Data must be a bytestring
    data = data.encode("utf-8")
    # When you publish a message, the client returns a future.
    future = publisher.publish(topic_path, data=data)
    print(future.result())

print("Published messages.")
```

requirements.txt

```
google-cloud-pubsub
```

This is full function code

```py
import base64

def hello_pubsub(event, context):
     print("""This Function was triggered by messageId {} published at {}
     """.format(context.event_id, context.timestamp))

     if 'data' in event:
          name = base64.b64decode(event['data']).decode('utf-8')
     else:
          name = 'World'
     print('Hello {}!'.format(name))
```

Expected output

```
This Function was triggered by messageId 1449686821351887 published at 2020-08-20T21:26:30.600Z
```

The logs may appears with a delay of 10-30 secs on stackdriver

Comment: Hi Hernández,

Thanks for your response.

Yes, I am manually publishing messages to pubsub topic. I even try to create a new cloud function and paste the same code. Function deployment is okay but I cannot see any logs in stack driver. 
I tried passing the JSON value in the testing tab under cloud function. Function execution was okay without any error but there were no logs for the cloud function.

I double-check the indentation, verified that the function getting call is the same, publishing to the same topic. The weird part is I am not getting any error, so it's very tough to debug

Comment: @ArvindSharma I recommend you to open a [Public issue tracker](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers) in order to find why your function is not logging